# Edit resource file C#

Tags: c#, resources, embedded-resource, xelement

I added to my c# project an XML file as a Resource file (Resources -> Add Resource (down arrow) add existing file.)

I am reading from the file with no problems :

```
static XElement resource;
static List<PageType> allPageType;
    

   static public List<PageType> getAllPageLayout()
    {
        
        try 
        {
             resource = XElement.Parse(Properties.Resources.PageTypeConfig);
          
        }
        catch { }
        var query = from p in resource.Elements()
                    select new PageType() 
                    {
                        name = p.Element("name").Value,
                        columnNumber = Int32.Parse(p.Element("ColNumber").Value),
                        rowNumber = Int32.Parse(p.Element("rowNumber").Value),
                        columnWidth = Double.Parse(p.Element("colWidth").Value),
                        rowHeight = Double.Parse(p.Element("rowHeight").Value)
                    }; 
        
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

but I could not find way to **add**  or **modify** the resource file element.

Comment: This is not clear. You added a resource file, and now you can't add it? What do you mean?

Comment: I think he wants to edit it from the program during runtime. I don't think it's possible, since the assembly is locked while the program is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change embedded resources.